# Variadic Templates and Template Classes

Tags: c++

I am trying to build some kind of Transitiontable for a StateMachine. I am pretty new to templates. So please forgive me if i made a stupid mistake.

This is my code for the Transitiontable class: .cpp and .h

```
template<typename T, typename ...Arg>
class TransitionTable
{
public:

    TransitionTable(T first, Arg... rest);
    ~TransitionTable();
};

template <typename T, typename ... Arg>
TransitionTable<T, Arg...>::TransitionTable(T first, Arg... rest) {
    std::cout << "New Transition Table" << std::endl;
    std::unique_ptr<T> Test = new T;
    TransitionTable(rest...);
}

template <typename T, typename ... Arg>
TransitionTable<T, Arg...>::~TransitionTable() {}
```

This is my Main():

```
int main() {

    TransitionTable
        <
        State1, State2, Event1,
        State1, State3, Event2,
        State2, State3, Event1,
        State2, State1, Event2,
        State3, State1, Event1,
        State3, State2, Event2

        > test(State1, State2, Event1,
            State1, State3, Event2,
            State2, State3, Event1,
            State2, State1, Event2,
            State3, State1, Event1,
            State3, State2, Event2);


    return 0;
}
```

So i am trying to create a new State and delete the new State right after again with that unique Pointer. This is just for me trying to understand more about Variadic Templates. The StateClasses Con and Destruktor all got a cout within them which say if they build or deleted themselfs.

Example for a StateClass. They all look the same:

```
public:
    State1(){
        std::cout << "State1 erstellt! " << m_Name << "\n";
    }

    virtual ~State1() {
        std::cout << "State1 zerstoert! " << m_Name << "\n";
    }

    void Entry() override {
        std::cout << "Entry State1!\n";
    }

    void Exit() override {
        std::cout << "Exit State1!\n";
    }

private:
    std::string m_Name;
};
```

My Problem now is that it's basicly doing nothing.. Can someone tell me please why? If I set a Breakpoint right at the start, the Debugger never even opens up.

Greetings and thanks for help!

Edit:

Statemachine .cpp

```
StateMachine::StateMachine(): m_InitState(m_CurrentState) {}

StateMachine::StateMachine(std::string na, trans_map trans, AbstractState* init): m_Name(na),
                                                                                  m_InitState(init),
                                                                                  m_TransitionTable(trans) {}

StateMachine::~StateMachine() = default;

void StateMachine::Start() {
    m_CurrentState = m_InitState;
    std::cout << "Zustandsmachine gestartet!\n";
    m_CurrentState->Entry();
}

void StateMachine::Stop() {
    m_CurrentState->Exit();
    m_CurrentState = nullptr;
    std::cout << "Zustandsmachine gestoppt!\n";
}

void StateMachine::HandleEvent(AbstractEvent* ev) {

    for(auto outer_map : m_TransitionTable) {
        if(outer_map.first == m_CurrentState) {
            if(outer_map.second.find(ev)->second)
                m_NextState = outer_map.second.find(ev)->second;
        }
    }
    if (m_CurrentState != m_NextState)
        Transition();
}


void StateMachine::Transition() {

    m_CurrentState->Exit();
    m_NextState->Entry();
    m_CurrentState = m_NextState;

}

void StateMachine::SetInitState(AbstractState* init) {
    m_InitState = init;
}

void StateMachine::CreateTransitionTable(const trans_map& transition) {
    m_TransitionTable = transition;
}

AbstractState* StateMachine::GetCurrentState() const {
    return m_CurrentState;
}
```

Statemachine .h

```
#pragma once
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "AbstractState.h"
#include "AbstractEvent.h"



typedef std::map<AbstractEvent*, AbstractState* > trans_map_inner;
typedef std::map<AbstractState*, trans_map_inner> trans_map;



class StateMachine{
public:

    StateMachine();
    StateMachine(std::string na, trans_map trans, AbstractState* init);
    ~StateMachine();

    void Start();

    void Stop();

    void HandleEvent(AbstractEvent* ev);


    void Transition();

    void SetInitState(AbstractState* init);

    void CreateTransitionTable(const trans_map& transition);

    AbstractState* GetCurrentState() const;
private:
    std::string m_Name;
    AbstractState* m_CurrentState = nullptr;
    AbstractState* m_NextState = nullptr;
    AbstractState* m_InitState;
    trans_map m_TransitionTable;

};
```

The Abstractstate and Abstactevent class are just small AbstractClasses.

Comment: c++??. Would do you mean with: ''This is my code for the Transitiontable class: .cpp and .h''. Since it is a template class all code has to be available at callsite -> only header. If I remember correctly the `TransitionTable` in the body of your contructor is short for `TransitionTable<T,Arg...>`, so I would expect some number of parameter error. But since you did not mention something like that I must be wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that you are running a debug build? What IDE/compiler are you using?

Comment: I think you are correct. I remember something like everything has to be in the Header, but that didnt fix my Problem... I am using VS 2015 Pro. Compiler is g++ I guess ? But i am not sure. Yes i am sure that i run the Debug.

Comment: @HenningWilmer No, if you're using `Visual Studio` your compiler is the `VC++` compiler

Comment: @WBuck Thanks! Good to know.

Comment: use auto to infer the correct type, for your own mind-safety

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is that this

```
TransitionTable
    <
    State1, State2, Event1,
    State1, State3, Event2,
    State2, State3, Event1,
    State2, State1, Event2,
    State3, State1, Event1,
    State3, State2, Event2

    > test(State1, State2, Event1,
        State1, State3, Event2,
        State2, State3, Event1,
        State2, State1, Event2,
        State3, State1, Event1,
        State3, State2, Event2);
```

does not call the constructor as you may think. What you've written there is the declaration of a function that returns a `TransitionTable<State1, State2, …>` and takes parameters of types `State1, State2, …`. So your code does indeed not do anything except declare a function and return 0. This is also known as the [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). If you wanted this to be a constructor call, you'd have to create objects of types `State1, State2, …` and provide those as arguments to the constructor. `State1, State2, …` is not a list of function call arguments, it's a list of types…

Comment: Thank you very much. This explains it. My Problem is I dont want to create Objects. I only want to create the State that is currently active and destroy it, if it leaves the state.

Comment: @HenningWilmer Ok, but then why does your `TransitionTable` expect one object of every kind of state as argument?

Comment: I would say because its wrong. I want a TransitionTable that takes alle Stateclasses and if i need to handle an event i want to look into the TransitionTable and create from that a new Object of the Nextstate.

Comment: @HenningWilmer Well, your `TranstitionTable` knows all the state types so it should be capable to create state objects as needed. But to do so, it will have to somehow know which state it's in and have information concerning which state to transition from where it is. Your question does not seem to indicate how all that is supposed to be handled…

Comment: I got a Statemachine class which handles all of this. And the transitions are inside of the code above. So if its for exsample in State1 and Event1 comes up it switches into State2.. But could you explain to me how to extract the Statetypes? And how does the Transitiontable know all the States? I

Comment: @HenningWilmer it's unclear to me how exactly you intend to be using the `TransitionTable` class. Could you update your question with an example for how you intend it to be used?

Comment: @HenningWIlmer it may actually be better to ask this in a separate question since the original question here has been answered it would seem…

Comment: Also, I think you may be walking into [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) territory here, so maybe consider that when asking your question.

Comment: I am at the beginning of my "StateMachine" Framework. I made a small one with States on the Stack that worked fine, but now i want to get the Objects off the stack. I updated the code with the Statemachine Class. But if you cant help me its fine. I will figure out a soluten somehow.

Comment: Ah I see. I dont want to bother you to much so its fine.

Comment: @HenningWilmer It's not so much about bothering me (I'm answering here out of my own free will, mind you ;-) than it is about repurposing an existing question to ask another, completely different question. It would be rather confusing to someone stumbling upon this question in the future to see it end up dealing with a completely different problem than what was originally asked. And, by asking a new question, you also get a chance at getting more and better answers to the problem.

Comment: I asked another Question. You were right this gets a bit confusing here.